# Singing from diaphragm

Tags: voice

I have been looking about singing from the diaphragm. Most sites say to attempt to keep the diaphram still, while others say to push it or to just ignore it all together.

I am slightly confused about this. Should I practice singing from the diaphram or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

"Singing from the diaphragm", like singing in the mask and some other recipes is not exactly overly anatomically correct but more describes a sensation than an actual action.  The principal action of the diaphragm is for breathing *in* rather than out.  The fundamental idea is to make use of the full elasticity and capacity of your air paths and not constrict them in a higher location.  So the important thing is not as much what you do with your diaphragm but rather with your air.  The feeling you should be aiming for is to have a connected air column and connected resonances between your "mask" and your diaphragm and not use your throat for sound production.

Mind you: anatomically that's a lot of nonsense.  As an idea or sensation to aim for, it pretty good describes a useful openness and connectedness of your singing support apparatus.

Answer (score 0):

I have not trained in voice extensively, but I would think that all three are not necessarily mutually exclusive. I would think the main thing would be to maintain an even and consistent airflow. If you try and push with an s sound and try and keep an even sound you will notice that you are flexing the abdominal muscles but they are not necessarily moving very much so you are both pushing but also keeping sort of still. And the goal would be to do this in a way where you eventually ignore it. And remember that you don't actually sing from your diaphragm. Your muscles control your diaphragm which pulls and pushes your lungs which controls the air that passes through your vocal chords. Like the bellows of an accordion, you want to keep an even stream. Anyway that's my theory.

Answer (score 0):

You should first learn about breath control, since that's the most important part on keeping a consistent tone. The your singing will improve dramatically.

You may be confusing the abdominal muscles with the diaphragm, because from my experience you keep the abdomen open and consistent while pulling upwards with your diaphragm to push the air out.

The process goes something like this:

1. Breath in with the diaphragm; meaning you suck the air inwards with the diaphragm, not the upper chest. Your upper chest should remain relaxed while the diaphragm pulls the air inward. The bottom of your abdomen should expand for the most part.
2. Exhale by keeping the abdomen's shape consistent with step 1; while "pulling" (to me it feels that way) upwards with the diaphragm. While the air is let out your abdomen will slowly get smaller.

Doing breath control exercises is my best recommendation. A quick search on Breath Control yielded this page which has some good starting points:

[enter link description here](http://www.vocalist.org.uk/breathing_exercises.html)

Something on that page really stood out to me:

*Once you get it right, practice as often as possible, sitting, standing and whilst at work until you are breathing naturally from your abdomen.*

After a while your natural breathing will even change for the better.